# how create histogram from data frame in R

Tags: r, histogram

I want create histogram from data frame, but every time code is used I get error `'x' must be numeric`.

```
    df <- data.frame(col1 = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120),
    col2 = c(10, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 72, 82, 92, 104, 114, 134))

    hist(df)
```

Comment: `df$col1` and `df$col2` are numeric.

Comment: You can't create histogram out of data frame. Base `hist` function expects numeric vector (i.e. column from data frame). `ggplot` can work with data frame, but will use values from one column anyway (although it may use another column for grouping purposes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do

```
hist(df$col1)
```

or

```
with(df, hist(col2))
```

If you want all the columns each in their own histograms you could perhaps do something like

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
histout=apply(df,2,hist)
```

Answer (score 4):

Please consider other visualizations for your example, as a histogram may not be the best for comparing the very similar data in col1 and col2.
In your case, it would be useful to transform your df first into a tidy format

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df_tidy <- gather(df, cols, value)
```

and then use one of the following charts that highlight the small differences in the data:

as density chart:

```
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_density(aes(color=cols))
```

or scatter plot:

```
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = value, y=cols)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=cols), size=3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,25,50,75,100,125))
```

or boxplot:

```
ggplot(df_tidy, aes(x = cols, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=cols))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a histogram of all the data, you can use

```
hist(c(df$col1,df$col2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use the ggplot library
here is an example

```
generateHistogram  <- function(columnName) {
  #I used library(ggplot2)
  houseDFPlot <- ggplot(data=DF, aes(x=DF[columnName]))
  #layering
  houseDFPlot + geom_histogram()
}
```